# Highcharts - how to set textShadow for data labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set textShadow property to style of data labels but it doesn't work (ignored):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar',
                 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
          textShadow: "2px 2px #ff0000",
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0,
           176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
  }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TJFBy/

Is there a way to apply a drop shadow to data labels? The reason is to make labels look similar to graph line.

Comment: Could you provide additional information? I'm looking at this in Chrome, and this is working fine...

Comment: @NT3RP, you're right. It works in Chrome and Safari, but doesn't work in Opera, IE9 and FF5.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are working in fiddle, you should change the current JQuery library (you are working with JQuery 1.4)
- You need to load hightcharts API.

  ```
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  ```
- And you should remove the 'comma' (,) next to the *textShadow: "2px 2px #ff0000"* line, many browsers don't render script code with sintax errors (especially IE)

Check the [fiddle fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/TJFBy/30/)